# Eliminating left recursion and left factoring this grammar

Tags: context-free, compilers, left-recursion

I have a grammar
 S-> SS* | SS+ | a

Really confused on how to remove the left recursion and do left factoring

My attempt on removing left recursion : 
S -> aS'
S' -> S+S' | S*S' | epsilon
If this is correct, I'm stuck in left factoring. Help!

Comment: Are * and + terminals or operators? We use operators for shorthand, but they are not part of standard CFG notation.

Comment: Did you see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) article in wiki?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

check this image the problem is explained

Comment: Please don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired,  [which we think is harmful](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

This is correct. There is an epsilon production.

Comment: Please don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired,  [which we think is harmful](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  Note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).